# Problems with closing Scanner object in Eclipse. Please read detailed explanation below

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 3 files. Two are preset and aren't allowed to be changed:-

1. userInputTest (containing "main" method)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class UserInputTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInput userInput = new UserInput();

        //Task 1
        System.out.println(userInput.sayHello());

        //Task 2
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userInput.readTenNumbers()));

        //Task 3
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userInput.readTenNames()));
    }
}
```

and 2) userInputTestsAll

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class UserInputUnitTestsAll {

    UserInput userInput;

    @BeforeEach
    void createObject() {
        userInput = new UserInput();
    }

    @Test
    //Task 1
    void testSayHello() {
        assertEquals("Hello Suzy".toLowerCase(), userInput.sayHello().toLowerCase());
        assertEquals("Hello Bob".toLowerCase(), userInput.sayHello().toLowerCase());
    }

    @Test
    //Task 2
    void testReadTenNumbers() {
        int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        assertArrayEquals(numbers, userInput.readTenNumbers());
        int[] numbers1 = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};
        assertArrayEquals(numbers1, userInput.readTenNumbers());
    }

    @Test
    //Task 3
    void testReadTenNames() {
        String[] names = {"Michael","Saru","Christopher","Sylvia","Paul","Harry","Phillipa","Gabriel","Jett","Ash"};
        assertArrayEquals(names, userInput.readTenNames());

    }
}
```

I need to write the 3rd file - called userInput (below), so that when userInputTestsAll is run, my file passes all the test. I have written the following (see code below) but, am getting errors because of the Scanner.close() method. It is for uni work and they insist that we close all Scanner objects after use. I know that closing the Scanner object closes System.in and it can't be reopened. Any suggestions please? When run in Eclipse IDE, the JUnit Failure trace has to come back green.

My code (which can be changed as required):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {
    // Task 1 - takes user keyboard input. Returns 'Hello' + user input
    public String sayHello() {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner object to read user inputs

        String name = "Something went wrong";
        
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine(); // read user input
                
        keyboard.close(); // close scanner object
        
        return "Hello " + name;
        
    } // End of Task 1
     
    
    // Task 2 - Reads ten consecutive user integer inputs from keyboard and stores them in an int array. Returns int array
    public int[] readTenNumbers() {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner object to read user inputs
        
        int [] numbers = new int[10]; // declare array to hold ten integers
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { // loop to read user input each time and assign to numbers array 
            
            System.out.println("Enter integer #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt(); // read user input and assign to array
            keyboard.nextLine(); // removes 'stray data' (including carriage return, etc) 
        }
        
        keyboard.close(); // close scanner object
        
        return numbers;
    
    } // End of Task 2
     
    
    // Task 3 - Reads ten names from user input and stores in a String array. Returns the String array.
    public String[] readTenNames() {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // create scanner object to read user inputs
        
        String[] names = new String[10]; // declare array to hold names
        
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { // loop to read user input each time and assign to names array 
            
            System.out.println("Enter name #" + (i+1) + ": ");
            names[i] = keyboard.nextLine(); // read user input and assign to array
        }   
        
        keyboard.close(); // close scanner object
        
        return names;

    }// End of Task 3   
    
    
} // End of public class UserInput
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including putting the scanner object and close method in a seperate method/putting the Scanner.close method just in the last method/etc. T
his is 1st year, 1st semester uni work and the first coding we have had to do on reading user input, so I can't see it needing to be so longwinded/difficult.

Comment: "It is for uni work and they insist that we close all Scanner objects after use. I know that closing the Scanner object closes System.in and it can't be reopened" Your uni is wrong. You are right. I suggest you put a comment explaining why you should/did not close `System.in`. But if the tests passed, what's the problem?

Comment: It is possible that it is okay to close `System.in` because it's mocked by the test suite, but still, the test suite should be responsible for closing it, not you. However, your code would _only_ work in a test environment.

Comment: The tests will pass only without the Scanner.close method. But, then Eclipse put a yellow triangle next to the file name (because the Scanner isn't closed) and that isn't acceptable according to the uni staff

Comment: "that isn't acceptable according to the uni staff" _What_ isn't? The warning or the fact that you didn't close the scanner? If it's the warning, you can put `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` and that will get rid of the "yellow triangle".

Comment: both the warning and not closing the scanner are not acceptable. I don't think suppressing the warning is going to be acceptable either. I appreciate your sanity but, I'm being forced to jump through hoops here by the uni staff. I've messaged the head of dept about this and will update here when I get a reply